# fourth-order multivariate Gaussian integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, integration, gaussian

I am struggling with an integral of form

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} y\otimes y~ \langle Ay,y\rangle \, \mathrm d N(0,\Sigma)(y). $$

I assume that it will involve the trace of some product of $R$ and $\Sigma$ to some power etc., but I cannot find a reference for it and I am unable to solve it myself. I tried applying a linear map to both sides, e.g. for $f,g\in \mathbb R^n$,

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n} f^\top y~g^\top y~ \langle Ay,y\rangle \, \mathrm d N(0,\Sigma)(y) = \sum_{i,j,k,l}\int f_i \, g_j\,  A_{kl}\,  y_i\ y_j\ y_k\ y_l \, \mathrm d N(0,\Sigma)(y),$$

so in principle this should be reducible to all up-to-fourth-order moments of univariate Gaussian distributions, but this is leading me nowhere useful since I cannot really enumerate all combinations leading to odd and even symmetries.

Comment: Have a look at  Sec. 1.4  of Janson's book *Gaussian Hilbert Spaces*   There he explains how to compute integrals of the kind your interested using so called Feynman diagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\s\Sigma$The $(i,j)$-entry of your matrix integral is
$$\sum_{k,l}A_{kl}\,EY_iY_jY_kY_l,$$
where $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ is a Gaussian zero-mean random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$. In turn, the expectations $EY_iY_jY_kY_l$ can be computed using the [Isserlis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem#Even_case):
$$EY_iY_jY_kY_l=\s_{ij}\s_{kl}+\s_{ik}\s_{jl}+\s_{il}\s_{jk},$$
where $\s_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix $\s$.

So, the $(i,j)$-entry of your matrix integral is
$$\sum_{k,l}A_{kl}(\s_{ij}\s_{kl}+\s_{ik}\s_{jl}+\s_{il}\s_{jk}).$$

So, your matrix integral is
$$(\text{tr}(A\s))\s+\s A\s+\s A^\top\s.$$